# Dropzone.js random upload fail

Tags: javascript, upload, dropzone.js

We're using dropzone.js with this options:

```
    $wnd.Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
          paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
          acceptedFiles: "application/zip,.zip",
          maxFilesize: 20 // MB
    };
```

The problem is that the upload stops randomly for a file that is just 13MB or even 10MB what could be wrong with dropzone, is this a bug? Since when we use Rest/curl or Postman to upload to the same upload URL, the same file uploads without any problems?

- Is there an option for Dropzone to resume the upload if ever it breaks or something?
- What are the options to make sure upload works like what we can do with curl/Postman?

Comment: a) could be a size limit on the **server**, b) do you get any (relevant and useful) information in the browsers **developer** tools console or network tabs that could assist you in solving your problem?

Comment: Dropzone.js does not provide any error log except that the progress callback stops, and as I have mentioned the same file is uploaded using curl/Postman (same fize, same file) and the file is uploaded without any issue at all. The Dropzone.js in our app actually is able to upload files like 1MB to 2MB from what we have tested, bigger files just wont upload.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read about using curl - `is able to upload files like 1MB to 2MB` - I thought you said 10 or 13MB in the question

Comment: Yes sorry what I mean is using other upload client, the upload works fine, either small or large files, but with Dropzone.js it only works with small files